# Rails submit button is not saving data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using Rails 5.2.2. I am trying to use nested attributes with devise. I created the associations, migrations, and views.

Here is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :companies, :has_many => :users
  get 'welcome/index'
  root "welcome#index"
end
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  belongs_to :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company

end
```

Company.rb:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
end
```

My custom devise parameter permitting concern:

```
module DevisePermitter
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do 
        before_action :permitted_devise_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    end



    def permitted_devise_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name,:gsm,:role,:company_id,company_attributes:[:name,:tax_no,:city]])
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name,:gsm,:id_no,:profile_picture,:socials])
    end
end
```

When I click the submit button, it returns the same sign_up page without recording the values. Here is the server response:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up?utf8_SHORTENED-HERE" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-26 10:32:51 +0300
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yBS9+sMyfSq0BYAd5LuodZCuJ9vHLFaxohrZjbOCdmv1m4SYUVI4XpE2GKmeY1eM0GhHEgtcnBZK7I8c0PuAHA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"asd@yandex.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "company_attributes"=>{"name"=>"asd asd", "tax_no"=>"42123", "city"=>"asda"}, "name"=>"sadaf", "gsm"=>"1231313", "role"=>"asdas"}, "commit"=>"Register"}
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/devise1
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/devise1 (3.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 17.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

When i try to save data using rails console , it works :

```
User.create!({"email"=>"asd@yandex.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "company_attributes"=>{"name"=>"asdasd", "tax_no"=>"asdasd", "city"=>"asdasd"}, "name"=>"asdasd asd", "gsm"=>"313121", "role"=>"asdasd"})
```

I am passing something, but I can't find what it is.

Comment: It's not saving data to database?

Comment: You wrote that it is not.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Neither do I. .

Comment: You provided log for new form log `Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML`, Your problem must be in `create` action request so where is the log?

Comment: @ray . I didn't changed anything in create action because there is no devise controllers generated by me.I am using the defaults and this is the only output by server.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in `/app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :permitted_devise_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected
    def permitted_devise_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name,:gsm,:role,:company_id,company_attributes:[:name,:tax_no,:city]])
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name,:gsm,:id_no,:profile_picture,:socials])
    end
end
```

and comment out the codes inside the `DevisePermitter` and see what happens

Comment: Nothing changed. Completely same server output.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Problem was in my view and form_for tag was not generating  action="\users" and method="post" in form element.

Solved by creating a valid form_for tag.

Answer (score 0):

Remove company_id from permitted_devise_parameters method.

```
def permitted_devise_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name,:gsm,:role, company_attributes:[:name,:tax_no,:city]])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name,:gsm,:id_no,:profile_picture,:socials])
end
```